# Updating pytorch tensor by matching multiple boolean conditions on the original values

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I currently am updating values in a `Pytorch` `tensor` using multiple `OR` conditions:

```
>>> import torch

>>> my_tensor = torch.tensor([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

>>> condition = ((my_tensor==1) | (my_tensor==4) | (my_tensor==5))
>>> my_tensor[condition] = 0

>>> my_tensor
[0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0]
```

My list of conditions is much longer than the toy example above. Can the condition operator match a list? If not, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a combination of [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html#torch-where) and  [`torch.isin`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.isin.html) like below:

```
>>> torch.where(torch.isin(my_tensor, torch.tensor([1,4,5])), 0, my_tensor)
tensor([0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0])
```

**Update, Second approach:** We can use [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.1/generated/torch.reshape.html?highlight=reshape#torch.reshape).

*(`torch.isin` not exist in `pytorch==1.9.1` as you say in comment)*

```
>>> mask = (my_tensor == torch.reshape(torch.tensor([1,4,5]), (-1,1))).any(0)
>>> torch.where(mask, 0, my_tensor)
```

Comment: Thanks l'mahdi, i'll mark as accepted but I'm on `Pytorch==1.9.1` which doesn't have the `torch.isin` function. Is my current way the best for that version?